# Get sessions' remote IP from Teamviewer log file

Tags: log-files, teamviewer

I'd like to know who has logged in to my machine and when.

I have two TeamViewer log files: `Connections_incoming.txt` and `TeamViewer7_Logfile.log`.

The first one is quite plain and lists, as its name says, the incoming connections to the machine, reporting the local name of the remote host, login time, logout time, and some ids. e.g.:

```
173274362   MYLAPTOP    20-02-2012 17:32:16 20-02-2012 17:50:42 Master  RemoteControl   {C5AAE483-ED0B-54B8-9235-7AE597CAD342}
```

This is almost all what I need, but unfortunately no remote IP address is reported here, so I checked for IPs in `TeamViewer7_Logfile.log` but it is really messy. It indeed contains some IP addresses but I can't understand which one is bound with the items in the first log file.

Is there a way to interpolate the two logs to get what I need? Should I search the second file for some particular text? What do you suggest?

Comment: Easy, they both have timestamps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be easy to test.  Simply connect to your own machine from another machine and then look at the log file to see if that other machine's IP address is ever recorded.

You will see that the log files contains pairs like this

```
CT.Receive.CMD_UDPPING From=932536226 To=316426335 L=80
GWT.CmdUDPPing.PunchReceived, a=192.168.1.100, p=1565
```

`932536226` is the remote system's TeamViewer ID
`316426335` is your system's TeamViewer ID
`192.168.1.100` is the remote system's TeamViewer IP address

Comment: 192.168... looks like local IP, doen't it?

Comment: It's the local IP, not the remote IP.

Comment: @Jon: It is local network IP and also remote TeamViewer IP. He connected to TeamViewer in the local network ...